# How to switch off -reloadData's cell height animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a `UITableView`, its cells' height can be either 68pt or 78pt. For example there are two 68pt height cells and one 78pt. I add new object to the datasourse and then call `-reloadData` to refresh the `UITableView`. But when this method fires - appears animation of one cell height change and I'd like to switch it off.

Due to some limitations I can't use `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`.

Comment: Does it animate when you call reload data ? I thought you were reloading – reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Comment: No, I use reloadData. I suppose that this animation appears because I insert new cell at row 0 and other cells are shifts.

Comment: I wouldn't expect reloadData to animate unless maybe you were inside an animation block.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[UIVIew setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[tableView reloadData];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

to see if this is what you want. (animations in UIView are enabled by default)